# Select item in array that matches one item in another array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, where-clause, rails-activerecord

Problem:
Get a single record from the `contacts` table where the `first_name` and `last_name` is equal to those given in the params. If there is more than one record found, then return the record that matches a domain.

```
def check_cache(params)
  cached = where(first_name: params[:first_name], last_name: params[:last_name])
  if cached.size > 1
    # select the record with a matching one of params[:domains]
    # cached #=> ['bob@gmail.com', 'bob@yahoo.com']
    # params[:domains] #=> ['gmail.com', 'abc.com']
    # result would be bob@gmail.com
  end
  cached
end
```

tried this in IRB

```
cached.select{|e| e =~ /(gmail.com)/}
```

but not sure how I would check each one in the `params[:domains]`

Comment: If I understand the question correctly you could do something like `cached.find { |email| params[:domain].include?(email.match(/@(.*)/)[1])`. Let me know if that works as I'm not sure of the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
if cached.size > 1   
  params[:domains].each do |domain|
    cached.select do |result|
      result_domain = result.split("@").last

      return result if result_domain == domain
    end
  end
end
```